# Combine two rows into one

Tags: postgresql

The below query gives me two rows for the one student because there are two contacts for the student. What I would like to be able to do though, is display both contacts in the one row.

I would be most appreciative if someone was able to assist me.

Query

```
select student.code as "student code", student.firstname, student.surname, student.birth_date, contact.firstname as "contact firtname", contact.surname as "contact surname"
from 
student
join "studentContact" on student.id = "studentContact".student
join contact on "studentContact".contact = contact.id
```

Output

```
student code  firstname surname birthdate   contact firstname   contact surname
1234           John      Doe    19/09/2000  Jane                Doe 
1234           John      Doe    19/09/2000  Harry               Doe
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use `string_agg` function. 
Something like this:

```
select student.code as "student code", student.firstname, student.surname, student.birth_date, string_agg(concat(contact.firstname, ' ', contact.surname), ', ') as "contacts"
from 
student
join "studentContact" on student.id = "studentContact".student
join contact on "studentContact".contact = contact.id
group by student.id
```

Comment: This assumes that `id` is the primary key of table `student`. Most likely a valid assumption given the join conditions, but worthwhile mentioning.